# Socket.io : sending to all clients in a namespace, excluding sender

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have seen this [socket.io cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/) from the official socket.io site and some answers here on stack overflow. I did not find the answer I was looking for.

How can I send to all clients in a namespace, except the sender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the socket is connected to a namespace then you forward the message using socket.broadcast.emit

```
const app = require("express")();
const http = require("http").createServer(app);
const PORT = 3000;
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("<h1>This is a socket io server</h1>");
});

http.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

io.of("/").on("connection", function(socket) {
});

io.of("chat").on("connection", function(socket) {
  socket.on("message", data => {
    // socket is connected to namespace so just broadcast the emit to other clients in the namespace
    socket.broadcast.emit("message", {
      user: socket.id,
      message: data.message
    });
  });
});
```